# Google Analytics API : Required parameter is missing: grant_type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, dashing

So I'm creating a dashboard using dashing (sinatra based framework) and I need to get data from Analytics API, and display it in the dashboard.
So I have the following ruby code, and the oauth returns this error:

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
}
```

Here it's the code:

```
require 'openssl'
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
require 'google/api_client'
require 'date'

# Update these to match your own apps credentials
service_account_email = ENV['chrezworld@dashing-project-1297.iam.gserviceaccount.com'] # Email of service account
key_file = 'key.p12' # File containing your private key
key_secret = 'notasecret' # Password to unlock private key
profileID = ENV['77142386'] # Analytics profile ID.

# Get the Google API client
client = Google::APIClient.new(
  :application_name => ENV['dashing project'], 
  :application_version => '0.01'
)

visitors = []

# Load your credentials for the service account
key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(key_file, key_secret)
client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
  :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
  :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
  :issuer => service_account_email,
  :signing_key => key)

# Start the scheduler
SCHEDULER.every '5s', :first_in => 0 do

  # Request a token for our service account
  client.authorization.fetch_access_token!

  # Get the analytics API
  analytics = client.discovered_api('analytics','v3')

  # Execute the query
  visitCount = client.execute(:api_method => analytics.data.realtime.get, :parameters => { 
    'ids' => "ga:" + profile_id,
    'metrics' => "ga:activeVisitors",
  })

  visitors << { x: Time.now.to_i, y: visits.to_i }

  # Update the dashboard
  send_event('visitor_count_real_time', points: visitors)

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how old is that example. The Ruby API seems to be very poorly documented, and since it's still in alpha stage perhaps it changed a bit. I recently did a quick ruby sample and it works great with the latest version of the API `0.9.6`

First you want to go into the Google Cloud Console, and export a JSON key file for your service account. Then put it somewhere ruby can read it. You'll need to pass into ENV its path.

```
require 'google/apis/analytics_v3'
require 'googleauth'

ENV['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "service_account_credentials.json"

Analytics = Google::Apis::AnalyticsV3
analytics = Analytics::AnalyticsService.new
scopes = [Analytics::AUTH_ANALYTICS_READONLY]
analytics.authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scopes)
accounts = analytics.list_accounts
accounts.items.each do |a| puts a.name end
```

I find this is the easiest way to query the Ruby API with a Service Account.

Also make sure to grant access to the Analytics account to your service account.

From there you can query other methods documented [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/AnalyticsV3/AnalyticsService#get_realtime_data-instance_method).

For realtime specifically you can do:

```
puts analytics.get_realtime_data("ga:XXXXX", "ga:activeVisitors").totals_for_all_results
```

Comment: I'm a "Ruby Noob" so I can't really understand what should i do. How do i replace your code with mine?
I mean... what should i delete of mine?

Comment: You should delete everything. Mine should run as is. Just make sure to have the json key and the latest version of the Google API client.